# Cross referencing nodes (php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, reference

i want to cross reference nodes.

The SQL Table looks like this:

> nid1 nid2
>
> 44 12
>
> 88 234
>
> 123 44

I have to check the references on each node. For example on node 44 i need to find 12 (nid2) and 123 (nid1).

How would you solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: How have you not seen an OR in a WHERE clause?  Learning SQL is my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from <table> where nid1 = 44 or nid2 = 44
```

Comment: Okay, but i have to select only the other nid (if nid2 is 44 select nid1 / if nid1 is 44 nid2